# output from python dictionary with unwanted prefix

Tags: python

(Disclaimer: Still new to Python and programming)

I used Python 2.7 and Beautiful Soup for a function that extracts data from a website …

```
date = soup.find('div', class_="attention-box").p.string
```

… running a regular expression, because I just need the year, not *Date:* and not day + months …

```
date = re.findall(r'(\d{4})\s+', date)
```

… adding it to a dictionary …

```
collection['date']=date
```

… and returning the dictionary.

When I tried printing the following (I am creating a template for a wiki) with the strings from the dictionary

```
print "|" + collection['URL'] + "|" + collection['title'] + "|" + collection['name']+"|"
```

it worked.

When I added *date*

```
print "|" + collection['URL'] + "|" + collection['title'] + "|" + collection['name']+"|" + collection['date'] + "|"
```

I got the following error: *TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found*

In my function I added `date = str(date)` and got a working output, *but* i get e.g. *[u'2001']* in the date section. How do I remove this in this visual unicode representation (?) in this particular setting?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Style of lists

First is a style thing: you can represent this:

```
print "|" + collection['URL'] + "|" + collection['title'] + "|" + collection['name']+"|" + collection['date'] + "|"
```

as this:

```
print "|".join([a[x] for x in ('URL', 'title', 'name', 'date')])
```

Demo:

```
In : a
Out: {'URL': 'example.com', 'date': '2013-03-13', 'name': 'Mel', 'title': 'Foo!'}

In : [a[x] for x in ('URL', 'title', 'name', 'date')]
Out: ['example.com', 'Foo!', 'Mel', '2013-03-13']

In : "|".join([a[x] for x in ('URL', 'title', 'name', 'date')])
Out: 'example.com|Foo!|Mel|2013-03-13'
```

### Use of re

The second point is that `re.findall` returns an array of all matches. You may desire to set your match to be use `re.search(...)` which you would retrieve with `result.group()`, or use `re.finditer` if you want to error check in case more than one match was found. You could also grab the first value of `re.findall`, but that seems inefficient given the other two options.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot. I wasn’t aware of the output of `re.findall`.

Answer (score 1):

`findall` is returning a collection (a python list).

If there is just one `date` matching that regex use `find`, or you can continue to use `findall` and access the first date using `date[0]`